# Please help to switch to Ubuntu Full-Time!

Tags: window, resize

My Window positions and sizes are never saved. When I open programs like:

Chromium, Code Blocks, XChat, Thunderbird, Skype and others. Set them in a correct location on one of my screens (I have 2x24' monitors), but when I close and open any of the apps again, apps will appear in a default location, with default size. Program that I use the most: Code Blocks. I set up window locations inside of it, set it up as I like, but when I re-run it - everything is reset to default:

Image: [My Window Setup in Code Blocks](http://s18.postimg.org/c4xlogv2h/Screenshot_from_2013_09_23_19_40_48.png)

Image: [Resets to a default size, position and view](http://s18.postimg.org/h64zpu2ix/Screenshot_from_2013_09_23_19_41_12.png)

And this happens to all of the apps.

Please advise how this can be dealt with.

Comment: Another option is to use a different Window manager. I know for sure that enlightenment can remember window size and position, and a quick test on Xfce showed that it remembers at least the size. I'd also bet, that KDE has this functionality, yet I don't have it installed so I can't test.

Comment: I can confirm that KDE has a *very* powerful array of window management options. This capability is provided.